# Can SwiftLint ignore classes (not files) by suffix? Namely SwiftUI _Preview classes?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftlint, swiftui-previews

Most of my SwiftUI classes have an auto generated (from template) `ClassName_Previews` class at the bottom of the file.

I'd like SwiftLint to ignore anything ending in `_Previews` for ALL rules. Or anything that extends `PreviewProvider`.

I know how to exclude files and directories, but not classes.

Is this even possible? Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Since I have so many preview classes, I'd prefer not to manually have to add `// swiftlint:disable all` and it's enable counterpart. I realize going forward I can add those lines into my template!

Comment: You of course have the right to not want to include the previews but I have to ask why you want to do this? Shouldn’t they be as easy to read and free of possible issues as the rest of the code?

Answer (score 1):

Here is possible variant

```
// swiftlint:disable all
struct Demo_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DemoView()
    }
}
// swiftlint:enable all
```

Comment: Thank you! I just edited my question to include I'd rather not go back and add those, but in the future can add that to my template. :) Which works for now!